# Servlets and downloading files

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I want to download an image file using a javascript client. Then I want to call the servlet in apache tomcat from the applet.

How do I host the file on tomcat.  i.e. the same as hosting it in the 'docroot' folder on regular webserver?

Answer (score 1):

Just drop the file in a subfolder of the `/webapps` folder. E.g. `Tomcat/webapps/images/foo.png`. It'll be available by http://localhost:8080/image/foo.png. Or if you already have a webapp, just drop it in the web folder (there where you also put your JSP files and where the `/WEB-INF` folder is also present).